# histogram for the probability densities

Tags: probability, math-software

Below are the questions and need inputs to create histogram using scilab.
Let $X$ be a random variable that is uniformly distributed over the interval $(0, 100)$. Form a new random variable $Y$ by rounding $X$ to the nearest integer. Form the random roundoff error $Z = X − Y$. Create a histogram for the probability densities for the random variable $Z$.
We have use scilab to create histogram. Please suggest.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically, one can determine that $Z$ is uniformly distributed over $(-1/2,1/2)$. This does not require any software. My guess is the histogram refers to a sample of the random variable under consideration, which can be similar, but not identical to the *pdf*. If so, I would proceed as follows:

```
x = 100*rand(1000,1) // taking 1000 samples 
y = round(x) 
z = x-y 
histplot(20,z) // using 20 bins for the histogram
t = -0.5:0.01:0.5  // the interval on which z is distributed
f = ones(t)  // the pdf is identically 1 on the interval
plot(t,f)  // plot pdf for comparison with the histogram
```

The output looks like this:

[image: histogram]